# CRM get stage Required Fields

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

**In Plug or workflow**

- How to get stage **IDs** or **Names** dynamically from entity
- How to get current stage **Required** fields **Names** dynamically not hard      coded Using c# or js or any other method
- if any idea, Share please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an entity's metadata from CRM by issueing a `RetrieveEntityRequest`. In the response you get an `EntityMetadata` object having an `Attributes` collection providing all attribute details you need.

The CRM SDK contains clear example code on this topic. More information about working with attribute metadata can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509035.aspx).

Comment: Thanks its gets all metadata about enity                                                    we need to Get required field for stage in Entity

Comment: Please mark as an answer if this solved your problem. It helps other visitors to quickly identify helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about the client functions to query the Business Process Flow attributes?

In CRM 2015 there is now clientside functionality implemented to the retrieve **process, stage and step** information.
With **Xrm.Page.data.process.getActiveProcess()** you can get the current workflow process and retrieve a **Process** object.

You can use the following methods to retrieve further and deeper information about the process:

Process:

```
string: .getId();
string: .getName();
stage[]:.getStages();
bool:.isRendered();
```

Stage :

```
string:.getId();
string: .getName();
int: .getCategory().getValue();| stage category Optionset
string: .getStatus(); | „active“ , „inctactive“
step[]:.getSteps();
bool:.isRendered();
```

Step (the attributes):

```
string: .getAttribute(); | logical attribute name
string: .getName();
stage[]:.getStages();
```

This works in CRM 2015  but not in CRM 2013.

You find further information here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn531164.aspx